# How to redirect calls from http://svn.example.com to http://dev.example.com:8443?

Tags: redirects, subdomain, iis7

How to redirect calls from http://svn.example.com to http://dev.example.com:8443?

Should I be asking our Cisco networking guy to set this up (and if so, what do I tell him to do?), or should I be doing it directly from the server (I'm running IIS 7 on Windows 2008)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in IIS 7. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28WS.10%29.aspx (Configuring HTTP Redirection in IIS 7)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by server redirect.  You can do it by script redirect in the actual pages that load.  You can use Meta Refresh redirect.    Because of the port, I don't think you can just redirect through DNS.

What web server are you on?